# How do I upload a graphviz (.dot) file to Neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j, graphviz

I have a large number of Graphviz files that I need to convert to Neo4j. At first blush, it looks like it should be easy enough to read it as a text file and convert to cypher but I am hoping that one of the python graphviz libraries would make it easier to "parse" the input, or that someone is aware of a prebuilt library.

Is anyone aware of, or has already built, a parser for conversion ? Partial examples are fine. Thanks

Comment: Another possible method would be to use GVPR (included in the Graphviz system) to parse the Graphviz files and produce the Neo4j input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably hack this together pretty easily using [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/). They implement a [`read_dot`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.read_dot.html) to read in the graphviz format, then I'm sure you can use one of their graph exporters to dump that back into a format that neo4j can use. For example, [here's a package](https://neonx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) that attempts to simplify that export process (disclaimer: I've never tried this package, it just showed up in Google).